# Why autohotkey cannot save {Backspace} as an input?

Tags: autohotkey

Consider the following code. After typing x followed by {Backspace} I expect to receive a backspace but autohotkey does not show a reaction. For other keys this problem does not arise. Is there a way to fix this code?

```
~x::
    Input Key, L1
    if Key=s
    {
    do something
    exit
    }
    else {
    send %Key%
    }
    return
```

An explicit example:

```
~x::
Input Key, L1
if Key=s
{
send blablabla
exit
}
else {
send %Key%
}
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `BackSpace` and all the other keys in the third `EndKeys` parameter of the `Input` command and then send the `EndKey` if it was pressed.

```
~x::
    Input Key, L1, {BackSpace}{Enter}{LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{Capslock}{Numlock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}

    ; If end key was pressed, extract it and replace `Key` with the EndKey
    FoundPos := RegExMatch(ErrorLevel, "EndKey:(.*)", SubPat)
    if (FoundPos > 0)
        Key = {%SubPat1%}

    if (Key="s")
        send blablabla
    else
        send %Key%
return
```

You can find more info about it in the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm#ErrorLevel).

An alternative solution is to use `A_PriorKey` to check if `x` was pressed before `s`.

```
; $ is required to prevent the hoteky from firing itself
$s::
    if (A_PriorKey = "x")
        Send blablabla
    else
        Send s
return
```

Comment: After typing `x` followed by {backspace} I expect to receive a {backspace} (thus `x` should be removed). But it is not the case with this code. By the way the condition `if Key=s` is not present in your code.

Comment: @Name Then change it to send backspace. Your question is not clear enough I though you want to do with backspace what you're doing with `s` I still don't understand what exactly you want to happen.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The main question is to wait for user input, if the user type some characters (say `s`, `t` etc) then do something depending on these characters (say sending `blablabla`), otherwise sending "exactly" what the user had sent (any key that the user has pressed). As you see, the end of code I have `send %Key%` to achieve this purpose. My original  code works for the usual characters in its "else" part, but unfortunately failed to function when the user send `Backspace` (and maybe some other particular keys) as input.